# Android - Adding inflated views to viewflipper

Tags: android, viewflipper, layout-inflater

first off I apologise if it's a dumb question as I'm a noob when it comes to Android and StackOverflow too...

I'm trying to read a twitter json feed and then push the various tweets into a ViewFlipper so it cycles horizontally between them...I just need the date (formatted) and the text of the tweet...
I've already got the feed working and I can cycle between the tweets, my question is how to inject them into the viewflipper?
Right now I'm inflating a layout xml and using addView to get them in there, which works, but I have no idea how to set the two textviews in the inflated view...

Is there another way perhaps that's easier?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Some source code

```
    ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.twitterFlipper);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

and the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitter_item, flipper, false));
            Log.i("first", jsonObject.getString("text"));
        }
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code so that we have context to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitter_item, flipper, false);

        TextView textView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        textView1.setText("Some text 1");            
        textView2.setText("Some text 2");

        flipper.addView(view);
        Log.i("first", jsonObject.getString("text"));
    }
```

Of course, replace the TextView resource id according to your layout.